# In OpenXava how do you prevent a link to an entity to be included in the main menu links of an application user interface?

Tags: openxava

In OpenXava, the menu is typically auto-generated to include all entities with @Entity annotations unless explicitly configured otherwise. I understand that this is relatively easy to do in XavaPro. For demo/ development purposes, is there a way to prevent an entity from being displayed in the main menu?

I tried to add module definitions in naviox.properties with no effect. I thought of adding the @Hidden annotation to the entity class. However this will hide the entity from all views, not just the main menu; it also hides the entity from all other views in the application, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an official way, but for me, the fastest was to set "display: none" on the undesired objects in custom.css. However, openxava is very mean in assigning class names, so finding a good CSS selector can be tricky, and an adventurous user can still re-enable it from the browser's developer tools.